# Sapui5 column adjusting

Tags: html, sapui5

this is how my view file looks like:

```
<mvc:View
controllerName="abc"
xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:form="sap.ui.layout.form"
xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m"
xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
<App>
    <pages>
        <Page title="APP_TITLE" showHeader="false">
            <content>
                <Table id="configTable" mode="None" items="{ path : '/'}">
                    <columns>
                        <Column id="bname">
                                                        <Text text="BOOKING_NAME"></Text>
                        </Column>
                        <Column>                            <Button icon="sap-icon://message-information" text="Info" type="Emphasized" press="handleMessagePopoverPress"/>
                        </Column>
                        <Column hAlign="Right" id="addItem" width="2em"></Column>

                    </columns>
                </Table>
            </content>
            <footer>
                <Toolbar class="sapContrast sapContrastPlus" width="100%">
                </Toolbar>
            </footer>
        </Page>
    </pages>
</App>
```

which will produce the following UI:

[image]

as you can see that button just destroys the whole column, there is a lot of space under BOOKING_NAME how can I adjust the size of the button to the column so it doesn't scratch everything? if that's not possible how can I align the text to the center of the column, I tried vAlign="Middle" but nothing changed..... I don't find anything in the sapui5 doc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually just solved this by adding another column in that layout and instead of using an button and icon I just implemented the icon

```
<mvc:View
controllerName="local.controller"
xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:form="sap.ui.layout.form"
xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m"
xmlns:c="sap.ui.core">
```

and between the colum the following:

```
                                    <c:Icon src="sap-icon://message-information" size="1em" id="infoDefaultCurrency" press="onInfoButtonPressed" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple workaround will be using css.You can use sapui5 predefined margin class for this.

```js
jQuery.sap.require("sap.m.MessageToast");
sap.ui.controller("local.controller", {

  doSomething: function() {
    sap.m.MessageToast.show("Hello UI5 World");
  }

});

var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
  people: [{
      name: 'Joseph',
      number: 1.618
    },
    {
      name: 'DJ',
      number: 0
    }
  ]
});

var oView = sap.ui.xmlview({
  viewContent: jQuery('#view1').html()
});
oView.setModel(oModel);
oView.placeAt('content');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>MVC with XmlView</title>

  <script src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" id="sap-ui-bootstrap" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"></script>

  <script id="view1" type="sapui5/xmlview">
    <mvc:View controllerName="local.controller" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m">
      <App>
        <pages>
          <Page title="APP_TITLE" showHeader="false">
            <content>
              <Table id="configTable" mode="None" items="/people">
                <columns>
                  <Column id="bname">
                    <Text text="BOOKING_NAME" class="sapUiSmallMarginTop"></Text>
                  </Column>
                  <Column>
                    <Button icon="sap-icon://message-information" text="Info" type="Emphasized" press="handleMessagePopoverPress" />
                  </Column>
                  <Column hAlign="Right" id="addItem" width="2em"></Column>

                </columns>
              </Table>
            </content>
            <footer>
              <Toolbar class="sapContrast sapContrastPlus" width="100%">
              </Toolbar>
            </footer>
          </Page>
        </pages>
      </App>
    </mvc:View>
  </script>
</head>

<body class='sapUiBody'>
  <div id='content'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have used sapUiSmallMarginTop in the sample

Comment: Don't abuse code block. The rule which doesn't allow you to post links to online ide without code exist because of some reason. Don't abuse code block to overcome that limitation

Comment: Please don't leave signatures under your posts.